# Xamarin.Android (Visual 2019) - sees released .apk as an archive - can't open/install

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, apk

I'am trying to run the released .apk file on mobile device (tried many of them) - but .apk is treated as an archive - can't open or trying to unpack.

I tried tens of apk releases. I have made everything like this way: release - properties - clean/rebuild/build etc - archive - distribute. Tried with Codeshrinker - ProGuard - but didn't see any *.cfg file. Another apks - works great.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I sent .apk file  through usb cabel and then it worked.